# Is there a stylistically neutral synonym for 'interlocutor'?

Tags: synonyms, style

> **interlocutor**
>
> *formal* A person who takes part in a dialogue or conversation.

*(from [here](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/interlocutor))*

If Lexico says some word is "formal", then it means it's formal AF (it flags them as such much rarer compared to, say, the Longman dictionary). I don't want to pose as some aristocrat without a reason. How can I express the same idea using everyday language? Don't suggest 'speaker', it doesn't fit (it's only applied to spoken speech, as I understand it, I need a broader term).

Comment: The question [Shorter way to say “conversational partner”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29388/) was asked on ELU several years ago. The short answer is English doesn't actually have any "everyday" words with the requested sense. If you don't like ***interlocutor*** you might consider ***conversant, conversationalist, discussant*** or similar, but none of those are in common use either. In normal conversational English we simply avoid constructions that would require such a word (because we *know* we haven't got one! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The other party" is probably still formal, but nowhere near as formal as "interlocutor".

"The other person" even less so.

If you are talking about someone on a telephone call, you might want to refer to the two parties as "the caller" or some other title that denotes who you were speaking to.